# Email validation that should end with .com or .org

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want the Email entered should be validated to end with .com, .org or .co.uk and so on using FilteredTextBoxExtender. Following is my code what I've tried.

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender23" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="txtEmailID" FilterType="Custom,LowercaseLetters,UppercaseLetters,Numbers"
                        ValidChars="_.@">
                    </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

Comment: Simply Use Regex for validation

Answer (score 1):

Email Address (Lower case alphabets, numbers, @ and dot)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender5" runat="server" 
FilterType="Numbers, LowercaseLetters, Custom" 
ValidChars=".@" TargetControlID="TextBox6" />
```

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-FilteredTextBoxExtender-Control-Example.aspx

Try using an escape character with _

Comment: Thanks, But this does not satisfy my condition. As commented, I guess I'll use Regex.